# Referenced project's DLLs are not copied

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a huge .Net solution with many projects in it, among all my projects I have 1 ASP.NET MVC4 and unit test project against that MVC4 project. All projects target .net 4.0 and Visual Studio 2013.

There is a strange problem that after I compile entire solution my unit test project's `bin\Debug` folder is empty, even I force to rebuild only this single project, still the same result. There are other MVC4 and unit test project pairs in the same solution, rest of them are just fine.

Anybody else in my team can compile the same solution code properly.

Not sure anybody also encountered same issue? I have Visual Studio 2013 update 3.

Comment: "Have you tried turning computer off and on again?" - In this case it would take a form of downloading full fresh copy of solution from source control. There is surprisingly lot of things to break in it accidentally and hunting them all is pretty much waste of time if you can get back to clean state.

Comment: I restarted machine, I have a fresh copy checked out from version control, there is no luck.

Comment: Just because it has to be asked... Are you sure that particular project is building to bin\Debug in it's current configuration? Are you sure that the rebuild is indeed succeeding without error?

Comment: @helrich yes, it is in current configuration. The build failed because it could not understand the referenced type in the MVC4 project, however VS2013 intellisense could recognize them. Even the build of the project failed, the reference DLLs should be copied locally at least.

Comment: Do you have personalized build configuration? If so, have you tried using one of your teammates?

Comment: @PTwr I don't think I have anything special.